# How to read data separated by a ',' in a text file in C

Tags: c, file, csv, text, input

I was wondering how to read data from a text file that has its data separated by a comma; for example line 1 of the text file says:
(Name,Integer,Integer).

So I tried using this code to read the code in but it didn't work:

```
while (fscanf(ifp, "%15s,%d,%d", stationName, &stationDistance, &stationDirection ) == 2) {
    strcpy(q[fileCounter].name, stationName);
    q[fileCounter].distance = stationDistance;
    q[fileCounter].direction = stationDirection;
    printf ("Station Name: %s \t Distance to Central: %d \t Direction from Central: %d \n", q[fileCounter].name, q[fileCounter].distance, q[fileCounter].direction);
    fileCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Name` contains spaces, then the format specifier that you are using will stop there and fail, you would need

```
while (fscanf(ifp, "%15[^,],%d,%d", 
           stationName, &stationDistance, &stationDirection) == 3)
 {
 }
```

The `[` specifier matches against the set of characters you specify inside the `[]` for example `"%[0-9]"` matches all digits from `0` to `9`, the `^` symbol tells `fscanf()` to match antything that is not the characters enclosed by `[]` and following the `^`, so you are matching anything except the `,` which is what you want.

In contrast the `"%15s"` specifier consumes all characters until 15 characters have appeared or a white space character as in `isspace(chr) != 0` have appeared which is why I suppose that your `fscanf()` was only matching two of the three values.

You was comparing the return value of `fscanf()` to `2` instead of `3` which I guess was because it was returning `2` instead of `3` and you knew that because otherwise the loop was not entered, well **that is a really bad thing to do**, because you are causing undefined behavior since one of the three parameters might not be initialized by `scanf()` yet, you copy the name with `strcpy()` and store the integers too.

Comment: Wow you taught me so much just that, I had no idea you could of done anything of that, thank you so much, however for some reason it doesn't go into the loop now?

Comment: I will need you to post data from the input file then.

Comment: The data goes as following:                                                                                      "Taren Point,10,S" -> next line "Ashfield,6,W"

Comment: The last value is not an integer, you cant read it with `"%d"`, why is the field an integer?

Comment: Thank you so much, stupid error

Comment: I have got it working, the only think that is stuffing up now is some of the inputs are decimal values to 1dp, how to I account for that? So for example [Taren Point,10.5,S] @iharob

Comment: @MattSolo You change the format specifier to `"%f"` and the variable type to `float`. You can also accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: One last thing @iharob, i was wandering why my names are starting with a newline for example station[1].stationName = [newline]Riverview instead of just Riverview And just like the detection of the comma, how do you detect and not include a newline when reading data? If any of that makes sence

Comment: The end of line is probably comming from the end of line, try adding `"%*[^\n]%*c"` at the end of the format, the `*` means consume and discard the characters.

Comment: Now it is skipping a line every time @iharob, so its only recording data from every 2nd line that it reads is this what it should look like "while (fscanf(ifp, "%20[^,],%f,%s %*[^\n]%*c" , stationName, &stationDistance, stationDirection) == 3)"

Comment: Ok I think I know why try this `"%20[^,\n],%f,%s"`

Comment: Now none of the strings are being read @iharob

Comment: Dw i just added the line "memmove (q[fileCounter].name, q[fileCounter].name+2, strlen (q[fileCounter].name+1));"